# My bundel ID matches EXACTLY with the provision app ID. Why doesn't it work?

Tags: ios, iphone, sdk, ios6

I get something like:

Code Sign error: A valid provisioning profile matching the application's Identifier 'bundleID' could not be found

Where bundleID is exactly equal to the AppID for the provision.

Why won't it work?

I already read the various other questions, but no solutions worked. Pretty annoying on Apple's behalf.

EDIT:
I triple checked. The "App ID" field of the provisioning profile matches perfectly with the "Bunde Identifier" field at the top of the project summary in Xcode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Crosscheck the appId with provision Profile created
- You can open the provision profile file using **textedit** and check for the appId it contains is the same you provided
- Download and install the provision profile **after removing the current one** from the organizer
- Target>Build Setting>Code signing Identity Debug and release changed to the current provision profile

**UPDATE :**
make the bundle/Identifier just "QtAnimatedTiles"
Then you will see the options in code sign identity 
Set it and run :)

Comment: Yup, all three steps did not work. I've quadruple checked times two that the strings match, and tried removing and recreating the provision profile. The problem is still there.

Comment: Target>Build Setting>Code signing Identity Debug and release changed to the current provision profile?

Comment: ?K there lies the problem.Double click on the provision profile ans add it to organizer .You should be having that app Id created profile certificate installed in your xcode

Comment: They _are_ added to organizer. Let me take some screenshots.

Comment: Two screenshots: http://50.116.4.56/~/img/xcode_provision_ok1.png and http://50.116.4.56/~/img/xcode_provision_ok2.png

Comment: What other info would you like to see? Here's the shot of the target summary: http://50.116.4.56/~/img/xcode_provision_ok3.png

Comment: And here's what the greyed out options look like in the build settings for the target looks like: http://50.116.4.56/~/img/xcode_provision_ok4.png

Comment: Ok, I solved it!! I changed the Bundle Identifier from "8M2AVD484Z.QtAnimatedTiles" to just "QtAnimatedTiles" and it worked. I don't understand why though... From what I've been reading the Bundle should match the App ID... Oh well. It worked. Any insight?

Comment: So the Bundle Identifier is "QtAnimatedTiles" while the provision App ID is "8M2AVD484Z.QtAnimatedTiles".

Comment: your appId is just that name and xcode check tht name for provision profile to choose and then run

Answer (score 1):

In the Build Settings of your target, check "code signing identity". If it has multiple entries, select the proper provisional profile for all entries.

Comment: I can't. It won't let me choose anything. It is greyed out.

Comment: See Lithu's answer, I've described more details and added screenshots.

Answer (score 1):

Please check these point:

1-> have you choose the correct AP ID for creating Provisional profile?

2-> Match the bundle identifier again.

3-> create the provisioning profile again as well as app id also.